# How many native audiotracks are reserved by the SoundPool object?

Tags: java, android, soundpool, audiotrack

If I create a SoundPool object with 20 concurrent streams

```
new SoundPool(20, ...)
```

How many native AudioTrack objects will be reserved by the this SoundPool object ?

Is the native implementation of SoundPool Open Source ? Where can I view it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to my preliminary testing, each time SoundPool plays a sound, it will reserve a native audiotrack in the system. So the number of sounds SoundPool can be playing simultaneously is bound by the number of free system audiotracks available. SoundPool performs no audio mixing by itself.